# storing attribute data for many product types

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I am in a bit of a quandary regarding my design for a website that has to keep track of thousands of different product types (e.g. cars, speakers, baby strollers, etc.) and store attributes (e.g. turning radius, maximum output, color, etc.) for each.

My understanding is that if people are going to be searching for, say, all blue baby strollers, I'm best to have a table for each type of product (in addition to a "generic" product table that stores things common to all products, like name and brand). If it weren't for concerns about searching speed I'd be keen to use an EAV type of model, but I've been discouraged from that based on things I've read.

This seems like a common problem, but I have yet to see a good answer for how to deal with what I'm trying to do. I know there are a ton of sites out there tracking this kind of data, but I'm finding it difficult to imagine that they've got thousands of different tables in order to have a "details" table for each product type. Is it possible they're all using EAV and that the EAV-naysayers, while technically correct, are exaggerating the performance loss of using that type of model? Or are they just using one big "product" table with columns covering every attribute, and just not worrying about all the empty values?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just know there's a common way of doing this, and I'd really like someone to let me in on it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever considering using a CQRS pattern instead?  You can create a read database, with a denormalized search table, that would be optimized for search.

- http://blog.fossmo.net/post/Command-and-Query-Responsibility-Segregation-(CQRS).aspx
- http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

You could use a database like RavenDB, a document database that's supposed to be really fast for reads, to gain even better performance.